# tap event not working in view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Please check the code below, what I am doing wrong? I want to output to console when tap event on body.

```
 Ext.define('iApp.view.LoginView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'loginViewPanel',

    config: {
        style: "background-color: #3f3f3f;",
        html: 'hello world',
        listeners: {
            el: {
                tap: function() {
                    console.log('tapped');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

no output to console...

Answer (score 5):

You are using an old version of adding an element listener.

If you use the [compat](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/building) version fo Sencha Touch 2, it should give you a warning in the console like this:

[image: console warning]

So your code should look something like this:

```
Ext.define('iApp.view.LoginView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'loginViewPanel',

    config: {
        style: "background-color: #3f3f3f;",
        html: 'hello world',
        listeners: {
            tap: {
                element: 'element',
                fn: function() {
                    console.log('tapped');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can find out more information about the changes on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?176239-HOWTO-Adding-Event-Listeners-to-Component-Elements).

**Update**

If you want to delegate to a child of the item, you must still target `element`, and then within your function check if the tapped element is the one you want:

```
var component = Ext.Viewport.add({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    style: 'background: red',
    html: 'Tap me<div id="test" style="background:blue;">Only this will alert</div>',
    listeners: {
        tap: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) {
                var element = Ext.get(e.target);
                if (element.id == "test") {
                    alert('tap!');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried element: '#mydiv' but its still not working. where mydiv is the id of an element in this view

Comment: @coure2011 I've updated my example to show how you can do that.

Comment: Take a look at the jog-with-friends app in the touch examples directory, your listeners need to be defined inside of your controller, you can see how it is done in that example app

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select an element by class or id, it's cleaner to use the delegate option:

```
var component = Ext.Viewport.add({
width: 300,
height: 300,
style: 'background: red',
html: 'Tap me<div id="test" style="background:blue;">Only this will alert</div>',
listeners: {
    tap: {
        element: 'element',
        delegate: '#test',
        fn: function(e) {
            alert('Element with id "test" was tapped!');
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('app.view.Card', {
config : {
    layout : 'card',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'panel',
        docked : 'top',
        html : "<img width='320px'  id='image1' src='images/im.jpg'/>",

        listeners : {
            touchstart : {
                element : 'element',
                fn : function() {
                    console.log('tapped')

                }
            }
        }
    }]
},
initialize : function() {
    // if recording/handling the event in the controller.
    this.relayEvents(this.element, ['tap']);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simpler and cleaner way of getting Tappable Panels**

```
 Ext.define('My.component.TappablePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    initialize: function () {
        this.element.on('tap', function(){
            this.tap();
        }, this);
    },
    tap: function() {
        console.log('I heard the tap!');
    }
});
```

And it can be overridden in child classes like so...

```
Ext.define('My.view.TestPanel', {
    extend: 'My.component.TappablePanel',
    config: {
        html: 'Tap this panel',
        style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
    },
    tap: function() {
        console.log('I handled the tap');
    }
});
```